# No 3D-view using pst-3d in pst-magneticfields

Tags: pstricks, 3d

I'm quite green when it comes to pstricks and I have problems with a 3D-output using the package pst-magneticfields.

The sample code for 3D in the [manual](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-magneticfield/pst-magneticfield-docEN.pdf) (page 12) is shown below 
(The preamble was not included so I added what I thought I required):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-magneticfield}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}


\psset{unit=0.7cm}
\newpsstyle{grille}{subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=blue!50,griddots=10}
\newpsstyle{cadre}{linecolor=yellow!50}

\begin{pspicture}(-7,-6)(7,6)
    \psmagneticfieldThreeD[N=8,R=2,L=8,pointsB=1200,linecolor=blue,pointsS=2000](-7,-6)(7,6)
\end{pspicture}


\end{document}
```

The output and how it was supposed to look is illustrated below:

[image]

What I get (above)

What I want (below)

[image]

The manual mentions the package "pst-3d" and an option "viewpoint", but adding it with or without the option has no effect. The log seems to mention that the package is already loaded.

I am compiling using xetex (which I am also unfamiliar with) using TeXstudio for mac.

Comment: `xelatex` can not handle the 3d view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem as you `xelatex` under `MiKTeX`.

HOWEVER: if you compile with `pdflatex`, loading the `auto-pst-pdf` package, and adding the `-shell-escape` switch  to `pdflatex`, it works fine:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-magneticfield}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}


\psset{unit=0.7cm}
\newpsstyle{grille}{subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=blue!50,griddots=10}
\newpsstyle{cadre}{linecolor=yellow!50}

\begin{pspicture}(-7,-6)(7,6)
    \psmagneticfieldThreeD[N=8,R=2,L=8,pointsB=1200,linecolor=blue,pointsS=2000](-7,-6)(7,6)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are absolutely correct. This is by far the best solution as I now dont have to switch back and forth from pdflatex and xetex. Thank you

Comment: @Bernard this simply produces a long white block output for me. I have added -shell-escape to the argument list for pdflatex, but it still will not work. Can you offer any help?

Comment: @Bernard I should add that I end up with two .pdfs in my directory, one with the filename and -autopp appended to the end. This file opens fine with a pdf viewer, but the regular filename.pdf will not...